# Call cakephp action with jquery and pass an array as a parameter

Tags: jquery, arrays, cakephp, action

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass an array I have in jquery to a cakephp action to do something with some data in the database.

I am not the lead developer with cakephp I'm just trying to figure it out.

Here is the scenario, we have a CMS we have built, there is a section with the pages on it. I want to be able to drag and re-order items in that list and then persist that back to the database. I'm using jQuery's UI sortable method for that and it's working like a charm.

```
var sortArray;
$( ".sitePages tbody" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-highlight",
    opacity: 0.85,
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.drag',
    update: function(){
        sortArray = $('.sitePages tbody').sortable('toArray');
    }
});
```

Which returns and array that looks something like this...

```
["53c6a933-1aa4-4228-979b-0caa72b40463", "53c6aa4c-ddd0-49ae-b8d7-0d3e72b40463", "53c690d1-51cc-4f08-bba0-061a72b40463",...]
```

I have an action in my controller that I want to fire that will be responsible for basically taking each of these items, and updating that row in the database, specifically the 'order' columns by 1 plus it's index once I hit a save button.

I'm a little confused on how I can get this to work. I have seen that I can call a cakephp action by just navigating to the url but I'm not sure how to pass the array to it, serialize seems to mess up my array and the url string does not look right at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX, you can return your result set to the controller by invoking the method (URL) (of the controller/method you want to use to parse and store your data) as the recipient URL on your ajax call.  Once the data is in your method you can use regular php to parse and save.

Comment: So I was able to get a serialized array working, and am now sending it to the controller and action like so
`$.post("http://"+ document.domain +"/site_pages/change_order_2/"+sortArray);`
Now in my model, I'm trying to figure out how to get it to save in cakephp, I was thinking something like saveMany would work but I'm not quite understanding how that works, also here is how I'm turning the query param back into an array
`parse_str($params, $output);` I hope that is right, I found it on stackoverflow somewhere.

Comment: Does your serialized array look like you want it to? In your model you should be able to just foreach through your array and update the db as you go.  This link might help shed some light as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392078/cakephp-saveall-updating-a-row-in-mysql-instead-of-saving-as-a-new-row

Comment: I think I'm just stuck on how to make sure I'm using foreach correctly with cakephp. I'm posting the data like this `$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/lifepark/admin/site_pages/change_order?'+sortArray,
             success: function() {
                 alert('success');
             }               
       });` and the query looks something like this `id[]=53c6a933-1aa4-4228-979b-0caa72b40463&id[]=53c6aa4c-ddd0-49ae-b8d7-0d3e72b40463...`. I'm just not sure how to loop over the data, in cakephp, that is where I'm stuck.

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to wait for my cakephp guy to help me because it looks like it's going to be very specific to how we have set up our system. Thanks for trying to help me though.